# SUM() of time column using MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I'm trying to create a query to sum time grouped by user and the result should be in minutes.

contents of table:

`duration user
00:06:00 user1
00:06:00 user2
00:04:00 user3
00:01:00 user55
00:02:00 user1
00:01:00 user2
00:01:00 user55`

Result expected:

`duration user
8 user1
7 user2
4 user3
2 user55`

This is the closer I can get:

`SELECT user, SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(`duration`) ) ) AS totaltime from salientes group by user`

However this outputs the result as 000:00:00 and for some cases, this ends on 838:59:59.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    mysql> SELECT MINUTE(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC( duration)))) 
  as tt ,user from tt group by user;
    +------+--------+
    | tt   | user   |
    +------+--------+
    |    8 | user1  |
    |    7 | user2  |
    |    4 | user3  |
    |    2 | user55 |
    +------+--------+
    4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: try this and let me know

Comment: This worked exactly as requested, however shows 59 as max value.

Comment: yes its getting that column value as minute so maximum minute value is 59 ;)

Answer (score 1):

`TIME_TO_SEC` only converts the time section so you end up with big negatives if the clock goes past midnight. Use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` instead to do the sum. Also `SEC_TO_TIME` maxes out at values greater than 3020399 seconds e.g. `SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(SEC_TO_TIME(3020400));` If you see this value 838:59:59 you've reached the max and probably just need to divide by 3600 to just show hours.